# How to persist bootstrap input type date to MySQL type date using Java entity?

Tags: java, mysql, twitter-bootstrap, spring-boot

So I have an

```
<input type=date" >
```

in my form,
and the User model that has

```
 @Column(name=birthday)
 public Date birthday;
```

Date being imported from `java.util.Data`

This needs to be persisted to a MySQL database, which has the following format. MySQL field is of type Date

```
yyyy-mm-dd
```

I tried changing the format using of the column

```
@DateTimeFormat(pattern = "yy-MMMM-dd")
```

but it doesn't work, I'm assuming because of the input type format.
How do I change this? I am using spring-boot.

Comment: Hi! Could you provide more details? If you are using spring boot which framework you have chosen to work with MySQL: Hibernate, Spring Data JPA, Spring JDBC template? Also please provide structure of MySQL table

Comment: Hey! Of course. I'm using Spring Data JPA. 

       `CREATE TABLE user(`
      `user_id int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,`
     `email  varchar(255) NOT NULL,`
  `last_name varchar(255) NOT NULL,`
      `name varchar(255) NOT NULL,`
      `password  varchar(255) NOT NULL,`
      `birthday Date NOT NULL,`
     ` PRIMARY KEY` (`user_id`)
    `)`

Answer (score 1):

I think you have problem with `MessageConvertor` you should define correct date format for Jackson ObjectMapper for that you should add these two beans

```
@Bean
public MappingJackson2HttpMessageConverter primaryMessageConverter(){

    MappingJackson2HttpMessageConverter converter = new MappingJackson2HttpMessageConverter();
    converter.setObjectMapper(getObjectMapper());
    return converter;
}

@Bean
public ObjectMapper getObjectMapper(){
    ObjectMapper objectMapper = new ObjectMapper();
    DateFormat df = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd");
    objectMapper.setDateFormat(df);
    return objectMapper;
}
```

After that simple rest controller should work fine

```
@RestController
public class UserController {

   @Autowired
   private UserRepository userRepository;

   @RequestMapping(value = "/user/",method = RequestMethod.POST)
   public ResponseEntity saveUser(@RequestBody User user) {
       userRepository.save(user);
       return ResponseEntity.status(HttpStatus.CREATED).build()
   }
}
```

Comment: Thank you!
But what I found working for me is adding  these annotations on my entity, now it works. 
        @Column(name = "birthday")
 @DateTimeFormat(pattern = "yyyy-MM-dd")
 @Temporal(TemporalType.DATE)
 private Date birthDate;
   But thank you so much!